# Usage of the word "gratis" in English

Tags: latin

As Spanish native speaker, I cannot find the context or usage of word "gratis" in English Language, as example:

> All apples are *gratis.*

I *know* (maybe I'm wrong) that it would be better to use:

> All apples are *free.*

Is there any difference in how these words are used?

Please provide examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, *gratis* is not used on signs in the way that *free* often is.

FREE APPLES

One rarely hears *gratis* used in everyday speech in the US, although it is hardly unknown or unused. *Gratis* is above the grade-reading-level for most daily newspapers in the US.

A publisher might send a teacher a *gratis* copy of a book.

EDIT:As CarSmack reminds us, it can also be used as an adverb, so that the publisher could send a teacher a copy of the book gratis.

Answer (score 2):

*Gratis* is a Latin word.  It means "free as in beer", not "free as in speech".

Answer (score 1):

Both are English words. Free is **much** more common.

Gratis is a synonym for free. You can find examples in the Oxford Dictionary [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/gratis). Click on "More Example Sentences." It can be used as either an adjective or an adverb. But it still sounds "Latin" and "borrowed" and sometimes it is used as a novelty word to appear "educated" or to attract attention. But the average American or above average educated American can go her whole life and never find a need to write the word "gratis." Read it? Rarely.

Answer (score -1):

Actually gratis means free of charge, without payment, according to [Collins English Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gratis), like in Latin languages including mine.

I understand that the word in question is not used in English and perhaps during centuries it lost its significance.

Comment: It's actually used a bit more in recent years thanks to Richard Stallman, but only in certain circles―I still wouldn't call it a common word, and I wouldn't be surprised if there are people who don't know it.